# How to build my HTML/JS/PHP project as progressive web app in visual studio?

Tags: php, android, ios, visual-studio, progressive-web-apps

I do have a website, which works with the following technologies:

- HTML *(index.html - in combination with Bootstrap)*
- Javascript *(some .js files)*
- PHP *(some PHP files)*

This website has more an app function. Why? Because my visitors are able to request some content from different sources, depending on their input. In addition, these different sources are hostet on different domains.

*(Here an example, for better imagine about my website: Think about a website which is an online calculator. The visitor can input some data. Regarding the data there is result. What I want to do is, this website convert to an an mobile-app, better to PWA.)*

**What do I want to do?**

I would like to build a progessive app, where I can build a mobile app which should work on `iOS` and `Android`.

**What kind of tools I do have?**

I do have `Visual Studio Enterprise 2017`. I think this `IDE` is enough to realize my project.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to use PHP on a mobile app (`PWAs`), which was build with `Visual Studio`? What do I have to take care?
- If I want to create a new Project on `Visual Studio`, I am able to create projects in different programming language. Question, in my case, which one would you recommend me to build up `PWA`? Which one is most compatible to do it stuff with mobile apps? Please check my attachment.

  [image]

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to create a responsive mobile *website* that is used from a mobile browser, or a native *app* that is installed on the device? The combination PHP/HTML/JS suggests "website", but you keep mentioning "app".

Comment: @rickdenhaan Well actually it was a website. But its an website, where you can get some content. So its like an web app for me.  But actually I want to my website to an mobile app. _(Here an example, for better imagine about my website: Think about a website which is an online calculator. The visitor can input some data. Regarding the data there is result. What I want to do is, this website convert to an an mobile-app, better to PWA.)_

Answer (score 2):

PWA is a Progressive Web App so I think you can't use langues as C++. Maybe C# but I don't know.

Yes you can use PHP to built PWA.

Use visual studio code if you like. You decide which editor or IDE you use in your project.

Guide that can help you:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how can I intragte PHP in PWA - do you have experience with that? Do you can recommend me a Guide / HowTo? Thank you.